# How to do action every X iterations until infinity in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Consider the following code:

```
i = 0

while True:
    # Do some other stuff first.
    # Check if this iteration is after 7.
    i += 1
    if i % 7 == 0: print 'Factor of 7'
```

This works fine, but the counter `i` will be a massive number sooner than later. Is there a better way to do something every X (in the above example, every 7) iterations for the long-term so that we don't have to store huge numbers? I have thought of the following:

```
i = 0

while True:
    # Do some other stuff first.
    # Check if this iteration is after 7.
    i += 1

    if i % 7 == 0:
        i = 0
        print 'Factor of 7'
```

But it seems that there would be a better way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Place a for-loop in the while-loop.

Comment: @MichaelButscher increased complexity, I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: @SANTOSH Fiddling around with modulo operator and checking with "if" isn't really simple either.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, I don't mean to be rude but I was talking about asymptotic complexity of using two loops, especially when there is no necessity to use it.

Comment: @SANTOSH If the number of iterations with one loop would be n then the number of iterations of the outer loop with two loops would be n/7. Inner loop iterates in sum (n/7)*7=n times. I don't see the difference.

Comment: Except, there is a cost to having extra register for loop counter. Anywho, It's a bad coding style as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to keep increasing `i` you only need to count to 7 over and over. So just reset `i` to zero when it hits your count. Then you need no division and no large numbers:

```
i = 0
while true:     
    # Do some other stuff first.
    # Check if this iteration is after 7.
    i += 1
    if i == 7:
        print('Factor of 7')
        i = 0 # reset
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use:

```
while True:
    for i in range(7):
        # Do some other stuff first.
    print 'Factor of 7'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
i = 0
while True:
    # Do some other stuff first.
    i = (i+1)%7
    if i == 0:
        print 'Factor of 7'
```